# calling my api is returning "Not Found" error

Tags: asp.net-core, dns, hosting, ionos

I have a .net core webapi that I'm trying to host on 1&1 vps that uses UBUNTU 20.04

I did all the steps from the docs and other tutorials : I downloaded the .net packages, published the project, uploaded the publish to the server, configured apache, created a service file and started apache and the service. and they are working properly.

I also downloaded the mssql package , and successfully configured my database.
Then I configured my project to connect to the database.

Now when I ssh into the server, and curl a get request (locally via ssh, i.e `curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/api/Category'`  ), it works perfectly and the response is returned successfully. (get on api/Category) for example.

but when I call mydomain.com/api/categories, I get

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache Server at mydomain.com Port 80
```

but for example when I uploaded an html page and called mydomain.com/index.html it was working perfectly.

Here's my service conf file

```
[Unit]
Description=ASP .NET Web Application
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/netcore
ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/API.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=netcore-demo
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and here's my apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess that You should ask this question on [server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) website not on Stack Overflow because it related with server configuration  not coding

Comment: alright will do, thanks